# Error al expandir los detalles PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

En PHP/SQL, tengo que mostrar los detalles de unos empleados de una empresa, los cuales están guardados en la base de datos MySQL. Ahora mismo, el código que he desarrollado es el siguiente:

**empleados.php**

```
<?php
  $host = "oraclepr.uco.es";
  $username = "i52calei";
  $password = "***";
  $database = "i52calei";

  $conn = new mysqli ($host, $username, $password, $database);
  if ($conn->connect_error)
    die ($conn->connect_error);

  $sql = "SELECT nombre, apellidos, edad, DNI, salario, telefono, direccion FROM empresa";
?>

<table border=1>
<tr>
  <th>Nombre</th>
  <th>Apellidos</th>
</tr>

<?php
  $rows = $conn->query($sql);
  if(!$rows)
    die($conn->error);

  foreach($rows as $row){
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row["nombre"].'</td><td>'.$row["apellidos"].'</td><td><a href="detalles_empleado.php?nombre='.urlencode($row["nombre"]).'">Ver detalles</a></td></tr>';
  }
  echo "</table>";
  $conn = null;
?>
```

**detalles_empleado.php**

```
<?php
  $host = "oraclepr.uco.es";
  $username = "i52calei";
  $password = "***";
  $database = "i52calei";

  $conn = new mysqli ($host, $username, $password, $database);
  if ($conn->connect_error)
    die ($conn->connect_error);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM empresa where nombre=".$_GET["nombre"];

  $rows = $conn->query ($sql);
  if (!$rows)
    die ($conn->error);

  $row=$rows->fetch_assoc ();
?>

<p><strong>Nombre: </strong><?php echo $row["nombre"]?></p>
<p><strong>Apellidos: </strong><?php echo $row["apellidos"]?></p>
<p><strong>Edad: </strong><?php echo $row["edad"]?></p>
<p><strong>DNI: </strong><?php echo $row["DNI"]?></p>
<p><strong>salario: </strong><?php echo $row["salario"]?></p>
<p><strong>telefono: </strong><?php echo $row["telefono"]?></p>
<p><strong>Direccion: </strong><?php echo $row["direccion"]?></p>

<br/>

<a href="empleados.php">Lista de Empleados</a>
<?php
  $conn = null;
?>
```

Ahora bien, el error que surge es:

> Unknown column 'nombreEmpleado' in 'where clause'

Creo que el error se encuentra en **empleados.php** en la línea de a continuación, pero tampoco sabría resolverlo

```
echo '<tr><td>'.$row["nombre"].'</td><td>'.$row["apellidos"].'</td><td><a href="detalles_empleado.php?nombre='.urlencode($row["nombre"]).'">Ver detalles</a></td></tr>';
```

Recalco que la tabla con los empleados guardados en la base de datos la muestra sin problemas, es al expandir la información personal de un empleado de la tabla cuando se produce el error

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Saludos, tu error esta en esta linea `$sql = "SELECT * FROM empresa where nombre=".$_GET["nombre"];`, me imagino que `nombre` es de tipo `string` por lo tanto tiene que ir en comillas ejemplo ` `$sql = "SELECT * FROM empresa where nombre='".$_GET["nombre"]."";`, como comentario tu codigo es muy bulnerable a inyeccion sql mejora eso con sentencias preparadas

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema en la concatenación de tu query, de tal manera que esta intentando buscar con el parametro 'nombreEmpleado' que no existe en tu tabla. Puedes imprimir el query que estas ejecutando con un var_dump($query) o con un simple echo $query, esto te dira si estas armando correctamente la consulta.